# How many hands are there with exactly 5 hearts after drawing 7 cards from a deck?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Draw 7 cards from a deck of 52 cards. How many hands are there with exactly 5 hearts?

Will it be something like $$\frac{1!}{(52!51!50!49!48!)\cdot(7!6!5!4!3!)}$$ 
I'm pretty sure its wrong, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The number you have is not even an integer.

Comment: And what kind of deck do you use? I think it's a 52 cards deck but you could precise it.

Comment: @Deuteu Sorry, should have mentioned it.. but yes a 52 card deck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $13$ hearts. You have to choose $5$ from them and the other $2$ from the rest of the deck which comprises of $39$ cards. Hence the total number of hands of $7$ cards with $5$ hearts will be
$$\binom{13}{5}\binom{39}{2}$$
The total number of hands possible is $\binom{52}{7}$. Hnece if you want the probability that a hand of $7$ cards had $5$ hearts it will be 
$$\frac{\binom{13}{5}\binom{39}{2}}{\binom{52}{7}}$$

Answer (score 0):

For a hand with fixed non-heart cards, we have ${13 \choose 5}$ possible hands where only the hearts vary. In turn, there are $\frac{39 \cdot 38}{2}$ ways of fixing the non-heart cards before we vary the heart cards.

So the answer is $\frac{39 \cdot 38}{2} \cdot {13 \choose 5}$ (which is the same as the other answer)